# How to query mongodb with mongoose + adding created date in results

Tags: mongoose

I want to add the creation date to results returned by mongoose. I know the _id property of a mongodb record has the creation date embedded in it, but I'm not sure how to add it to the result set so that I can use it in my client side application.

Any ideas on how to add that property dynamically to the results set?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `_id`'s timestamp as the date created

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      ... 
},
{
  toObject: { virtuals: true },
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
}
)


fooSchema.virtual('created')
  .get(function(){ 
     return this._id.getTimestamp();
  });
```

You can access the field `created` to get the timestamp.
The `toObject`([doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)) and `toJson`([doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON)) options are used to keep our virtual field(created) when converting from a mongoose document. Using `toJson` might suffice I guess, depends on your usage.

If you are not willing to use `_id`'s timestamp(there are many arguments that it is not advisable when operating across multiple instances), you can put it in a separate field like

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      created:  {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

This will set `created` to the timestamp the object is first saved.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose can do it for you automatically. according to [timestamp option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) in Mongoose just do something like this :

```
var nSchema=new Schema({
   name:String,
   ...
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' },
   ...
});
```

also you can track for update with `updateAt`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second way of ma08.Add a created field and use the default value to Date.now.This method automatically creates the current date as the created date.

```
var nSchema=new Schema({
name:String,
...
created: {type:Date, default:Date.now},
...

});
```